# Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I have docker 17.12.0-ce-win46 build installed on my window 10 laptop. Each time i start it I get the error below... I have followed all recommended solutions I could fine online on how to resolve this issue but the issue persist.

```
Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable
```

at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.ConnectToVsud(TaskCompletionSource`1 vmId) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 293
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 260
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 130
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 145

Comment: Thanks @Dimitriy, I received an update from data that resolved the issue

Comment: This is very bad issue with Docker in Windows. Docker is virtually useless - you don''t know when it'll stop working and you've to do all sorts of re-install, reset ... expecting something to work

Comment: I've seen this quite a lot in virtualized environments (Win 10 Pro running under Parallels or under Windows Server 2016 and Hyper-V). The answers here (opening up permissions on the disk and rebooting and exiting Docker) have all worked at various times... and sometimes not.

Answer (score 6):

For me, here is what I did to correct the error. Go to C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Hyper-V directory, right click on Hyper-V folder, select Properties, and un-check the Read Only checkbox and Apply changes. Next, in the Windows task bar right click on the red Docker icon, or if it is located in the hidden icons, select Quit, then restart it.

Answer (score 1):

You can revert to docker version 17.09.1.14687. 17.12.0-ce-win46 and 17.12.0-ce-win47 have this error.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Hyper-V using PowerShell
Open a PowerShell console as Administrator.

Run the following command:

PowerShell

Copy
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`
If the command couldn't be found, make sure you're running PowerShell as Administrator.

When the installation has completed you need to reboot the computer.

Enable Hyper-V with CMD and DISM
The Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool (DISM) helps configure Windows and Windows images. Among its many applications, DISM can enable Windows features while the operating system is running.

To enable the Hyper-V role using DISM:

Open up a PowerShell or CMD session as Administrator.

Type the following command:

PowerShell

Copy
`DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`

When the installation has completed you need to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your system variable(Environment variable) if DOCKER_HOST is defined then remove and restart system and run the docker.